# Restoring database failed in SQL Server 2005 enterprise edition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have tried to restore a database in SQL Server 2005 enterprise edition on Windows Server 2003. It shows the following error.

```
    Restored failed for Server 'MYS'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
    Additional information:
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version
 9.00.4053. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 
9.00.1187. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a 
backup that is compatible with this server.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Another point: I have to use the given .bak file. I have no choice without this backup file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4) on your copy of SQL server, and it will be able to restore the file without a problem.  The database server which backed up the database originally was running SP3, and you must have at least that version if you want to restore the DB.

Comment: I have tried to install SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 in windows server 2003. And failed to install. Shows following error message: hotfix.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: I have tried with following :
SQLServer2005SP3-KB955706-IA64-ENU.exe
SQLServer2005SP3-KB955706-x64-ENU.exe.

Comment: @Green Mile: I **highly** doubt you have a Itanium-64 bit machine - those are extremely rare. Is your server a 64-bit version of Windows Server 2003 ?? If not then you need to get the 32-bit version (the -x86 file) of the SQL Server 2005 SP3

Comment: @marc_s:: Thanks, Now I am downloading -x86 file.

Answer (score 3):

The backup was made using SQL Server 2005 SP3, but your server appears to be running an older SQL Server 2005 CTP edition.

You will need to upgrade your server to [SQL 2005 SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=0d878f4b-71e8-4170-9a14-1bce684811ce&displaylang=en).

Comment: I have tried to install SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3 in windows server 2003. And failed to install. Shows following error message: hotfix.exe is not a valid Win32 application. 
 
I have tried with following : SQLServer2005SP3-KB955706-IA64-ENU.exe SQLServer2005SP3-KB955706-x64-ENU.exe. what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the CTP
2. Install RTM
3. Install SP3
4. Restore backup
5. Hire DBA